# Wordpress post loop adding class

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am building featured posts section on my site using Wordpress tags (3 latest posts tagged as "featured" are being shown on the homepage) using this code:

```
                        <?php

                            $args=array(
                              'tag' => 'featured',
                              'showposts'=>3,
                              'caller_get_posts'=>1
                            );
                            $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                            if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                              while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                              <div class="featured-article">
                                <!--thumbnail, title and link code here -->
                              </div>
                               <?php
                              endwhile;
                            } //if ($my_query)
                          wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
                        ?>
```

Every entry is wrapped with "featured-article", but since i want the first post to be full-width and other 2 half width, i was wondering how can i add appropriate classes to them?
So, the first post gets "full-width" class and other two "half-width"...

I apologize if i didnt explained it properly (english not first language and all).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index of your post with $my_query->current_post while you're in the loop.

```
$class = $my_query->current_post == 0 ? 'full-width' : 'half-width';
```

You might also want to make sure that the class only gets applied to the first item of the first page

```
$class = $my_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ? 'full-width' : 'half-width';
```

Here's your loop

```
 <?php

 $args=array(
     'tag' => 'featured',
     'showposts'=>3,
     'caller_get_posts'=>1
 );

 $my_query = new WP_Query($args);


 if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
     while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

     $class = $my_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ? 'full-width' : 'half-width'; ?>

         <div class="featured-article <?php echo $class; ?>">

         </div>
     <?php
     endwhile;
 } //if ($my_query)

 wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
 ?>
```

Comment: This works great, but all the posts get "half-width" class

Comment: Now i am seeing "$class = $my_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ? 'full-width' : 'half-width';" above each post :D Sorry to be boring you this much...

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with counter.

```
<?php
       $args=array(
         'tag' => 'featured',
         'showposts'=>3,
         'caller_get_posts'=>1
      );

      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

      //add classes
      $counter = 0;
      $classes = '';

      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
          while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
              $classes = $counter == 0 ? ' full-width' : ' half'; 
 ?> 
       <div class="featured-article<?php echo $classes; ?>">
           <!--thumbnail, title and link code here -->
       </div>
 <?php
              $counter++;
           endwhile;
      } //if ($my_query)

      wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
  ?>
```

Or You can make a custom filed for addition class.

Comment: My php skills are pretty basic, but a question, what does happen then with "half-width" class for other 2 items?

I would use custom fields but client wants the cleanest solution possible (they dont want to add anything except the post itself)

Comment: Thanks a million dude! But, it doesnt work, i am getting an "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)" error

Comment: @neven-stepar please try now